# Why my Android device is registered at UrbanAirship without GCM Registration ID

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, urbanairship.com

I have integrated the Airship SDK into an Android app.
After app startup and Airship take off I'm getting the following debug info in my logs:

```
07-27 12:46:31.916 XXX - UALib( 1545): Initializing Push.
07-27 12:46:31.937 XXX - UALib( 1545): Push enabled: true
07-27 12:46:31.941 XXX - UALib( 1545): Starting GCM
07-27 12:46:31.941 XXX APID( 1545): f28dc1b8-76a7-4c2f-9135-66e968ca8922
07-27 12:46:31.941 XXX - UALib( 1545): Initializing Rich Push.
07-27 12:46:31.952 XXX - UALib( 1545): Registering default Actions.
07-27 12:46:31.953 XXX - UALib( 1545): Initializing Analytics.
07-27 12:46:32.025 XXX - UALib( 1545): Using GCM Registration ID: APA91bG3ae7LxgdhRBhpFOS7_QlA0OuYtg5CIoycO6v0moSziWBjycSSs-WMJJ8t6x9liRWi7jaWnaqnKuYU3ORA5S4hsn_vMkEz_7I1YWe76l7kdSiGwkPfc70q4oJCaSp-TaxX1WaHu0SWpX6XHbgwT4vsTABAI187A8xHTy4kGTUg0J6ywMo
```

But when I go to airship portal and review tokens - there is a device without Registration ID:

```
APID f28dc1b8-76a7-4c2f-9135-66e968ca8922
Status Active
GCM Registration ID None
```

[image]

And as a result I'm not getting pushes for that device.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already implemented the urbanairship API. At that time I was also searching for the GCM registration ID. But nowadays urbanairship has changed that thing. So there are two solution for you problem .

1. you can send push message using APID.
2. you can set your unique device id in Alias. Then using the API u can send push message to that aias.

hope it helps :)
please comment for further clarifications